# ChromeDriver does not handle ssl certificates when running in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

Below driver works fine when i remove headless option but when i include it the test fails. Using chromedriver version 2.36.540470

```
public WebDriver createDriver() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Dev\\tools\\chromedriver.exe");
    final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

    chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1900x1200");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");

    final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    return driver;
}
```

Comment: `createDriver()` method with only `final WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);` will of-coarse get you a blank / all white screen. Try to invoke an `url`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out chromedriver running headless does not deal with ssl certificates very well (current open issue with them). Switching to gecko driver fixed the issue.